# Java 8 lambda mutable variable capture from method parameter?

Tags: java, lambda, closures

I'm using AdoptOpenJDK `jdk81212-b04` on Ubuntu Linux, running on Eclipse 4.13. I have a method in Swing that creates a lambda inside a lambda; both probably get called on separate threads. It looks like this (pseudocode):

```java
private SwingAction createAction(final Data payload) {
  System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(payload));
  return new SwingAction(() -> {
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(payload));
    //do stuff
    //show an "are you sure?" modal dialog and get a response
    //show a file selection dialog
    //when the dialog completes, create a worker and show a status:
    showStatusDialogWithWorker(() -> new SwingWorker() {
      protected String doInBackground() {
        save(payload);
      }
    });
```

You can see that the lambdas are several layers deep, and that eventually the "payload" which was captured gets saved to a file, more or less.

But before considering the layers and the threads, let's go directly to the problem:

1. The first time I call `createAction()`, the two `System.out.println()` methods print the exact same hash code, indicating that the captured payload inside the lambda is the same I passed to `createAction()`.
2. If I later call `createAction()` with a different payload, the two `System.out.println()` values printed are different! In particular, the second line printed always indicates the same value that was printed in step 1!!

I can repeat this over and over; the actual payload passed will keep getting a different identity hash code, while the second line printed (inside the lambda) will stay the same! Eventually something will click and suddenly the numbers will be the same again, but then they will diverge with the same behavior.

Is Java somehow caching the lambda, as well as the argument that is going to the lambda? But how is this possible? The `payload` argument is marked `final`, and besides, lambda captures have to be effectively final anyway!

- Is there a Java 8 bug that doesn't recognize a lambda should not be cached if the captured variable is several lambdas deep?
- Is there a Java 8 bug that is caching lambdas and lambda arguments across threads?
- Or is there something that I don't understand about lambda capture method arguments versus method local variables?

#### First Failed Workaround Attempt

Yesterday I thought I could prevent this behavior simply by capturing the method parameter locally on the method stack:

```java
private SwingAction createAction(final Data payload) {
  final Data theRealPayload = payload;
  System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(theRealPayload));
  return new SwingAction(() -> {
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(theRealPayload));
    //do stuff
    //show an "are you sure?" modal dialog and get a response
    //show a file selection dialog
    //when the dialog completes, create a worker and show a status:
    showStatusDialogWithWorker(() -> new SwingWorker() {
      protected String doInBackground() {
        save(theRealPayload);
      }
    });
```

With that single line `Data theRealPayload = payload`, if I henceforth used `theRealPayload` instead of `payload` suddenly the bug no longer appeared, and every single time I called `createAction()`, the two printed lines indicate exactly the same instance of the captured variable.

*However today this workaround has stopped working.*

### Separate Bug Fix Addresses Problem; But Why?

I found a separate bug that was throwing an exception inside `showStatusDialogWithWorker()`. Basically `showStatusDialogWithWorker()` is supposed to create the worker (in the passed lambda) and show a status dialog until the worker is finished. There was a bug that would create the worker correctly, but fail to create the dialog, throwing an exception that would bubble up and never get caught. I fixed this bug so that the `showStatusDialogWithWorker()` successfully shows the dialog when the worker is running and then closes it after the worker finishes. I can now no longer reproduce the lambda capture issue.

But why does something inside `showStatusDialogWithWorker()` relate to the problem at all? When I was printing out `System.identityHashCode()` outside and inside the lambda, and the values were differing, this was happening *before* `showStatusDialogWithWorker()` was being called, and before the exception was being thrown. Why should a later exception make a difference?

Besides, the fundamental question remains: how is it even possible that a `final` parameter passed by a method and captured by a lambda could ever change?

Comment: I am not sure whether that's a *complete* example. I would love to paste the code and inspect it myself, but given what you shared, I just can't. Can you provide [mre]?

Comment: I can't give you a minimal reproducible example at the moment, but the code in the example should be sufficient to discuss the theory. From a theoretical viewpoint, how could the identity of a `final` method argument change outside and inside the lambda? And why would capturing the variable as a `final` local variable on the stack make any difference?

Comment: Today capturing the variable inside the method as a `final` variable on the stack no longer fixes the problem. I continue to investigate.

Comment: Given your use case, the only thing that's come to mind is serialization of the lambda; that would explain why the reference change. 
Also is the payload equals? Does it have the same content than before?

Comment: @NoDataFound I like your train of thought about serialization but I think even that shouldn't be possible, as to be serialized and deserialized the variable reference would have to change, and lambdas require effectively `final` variable references. To answer your other question, the content is actually different, which is why this bug came up to begin with; we would click a button and the wrong payload would be saved.

Comment: My train of though is that a lambda is still a class under the hood: the variables it uses are declared as private synthetic field (that what you can see when you debug) however serialization would certainly change the identity hash code, not the content itself.

Comment: You should perhaps try you chance with a debugger, some are capable of watching field update: you may try putting a breakpoint on the lambda synthetic field to see when it change. Otherwise, you could try with a private inner class implementing Runnable (with a final payload field): if that fails with that too, then you can debug from here.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that the bug here isn't coming from the lambda capture, but from the `SwingAction` itself. What do you do with the `SwingAction` returned from the method?

Answer (score 2):

> how is it even possible that a final parameter passed by a method and captured by a lambda could ever change?

It is not. As you have pointed out, unless there is a bug in the JVM, this cannot happen.

This is very difficult to pin down without a minimal reproducible example. Here are the observations you have made:

> 1. The first time I call createAction(), the two System.out.println() methods print the exact same hash code, indicating that the captured payload inside the lambda is the same I passed to createAction().
> 2. If I later call createAction() with a different payload, the two System.out.println() values printed are different! In particular, the second line printed always indicates the same value that was printed in step 1!!

One possible explanation that fits the evidence is that the lambda being called the second time is in fact the lambda from the first run, and the lambda that was created by the second run has been discarded. That would give the above observations, and would place the bug inside the code that you have not shown here.

Perhaps you could add some extra logging to record: 
 a) the ids of any lambdas created inside createAction at creation time (I think you would need to change the lambdas into anon classes that implement the callback interfaces with logging in their constructors)
 b) the ids of the lambdas at the time of their invocation

I think that the above logging would be sufficient to prove or disprove my theory.

GL!

Answer (score 0):

I don't find anything wrong with the captured lambdas in your code.

Your workaround doesn't change the local capturing as you just declared a new variable an assigned it to to the same reference.

The problem is most likely on your handling of the `SwingAction` created object.
I wouldn't be surprised if you find that printing the IdentityHashCode of that returned object where you are using it yields consistent values with your payloads. Or in other words, you may be using a previous reference to `SwingAction`.

> Besides, the fundamental question remains: how is it even possible
>   that a final parameter passed by a method and captured by a lambda
>   could ever change?

This shouldn't be possible at the reference level, the variable can't be reassigned. The reference passed may be mutable itself though, but that doesn't apply to this case.